# Running python 64 with shebang (#!) on Mac

Tags: python, 64-bit, shebang

I use python 64bit as follows.

```
alias python64='arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6'
```

How can I run python 64bit mode with shebang(#!)?

```
??? #!/usr/bin/python2.6 ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OS X 10.6 `arch` is `/usr/bin/arch`, so your line is

```
#!/usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6
```

In general, if you don't know the path you can always use the `env` command in the shebang as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Portability), which is guaranteed to be in `/usr/bin`. So,

```
#!/usr/bin/env arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6
```

will also work.

Comment: On many systems, this will pass a single argument with the value `arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6` to `env`, which won't split that value up. To my knowledge there is no elegant and fully-portable workaround. For non-portable workarounds, FreeBSD's env has the `-S` switch. For ugly workarounds, you do things like this: `#!/bin/sh<br>'''exec' /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6 # '''<br># vi: syntax=python`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/path/to/arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6
```

I dont have a mac to test right now, but usually in *nix you can find the path to an executable using:

```
which arch
```